# Why isn't this test for a file's existence working?

Tags: python, exception

I have a script that processes files passed to the script as arguments. If a file passed to the script does not exist, then I want to write an error message to stderr. Having read all the related posts that I can find here, I fail to understand why the following minimal working example does not work. It behaves as expected if the file exists, but appears to do nothing if the file does not exist.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse, glob, sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("src_path", metavar="path", type=str,
                    help="Path to files to be merged; enclose in quotes, accepts * as wildcard for directories or filenames")

args = parser.parse_args()
files = glob.iglob(args.src_path)

for file in files:
    try:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            sys.stdout.write('Fild exists: ' + file + '\n')
    except IOError:
        sys.stderr.write('File does not exist: ' + file + '\n')
```

Comment: is IO error the only possible exception?

Comment: If file doesn't exist, IOError is the only possible exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glob.iglob` is returning a list of files that *already exist at that path*, so the problem is you're only testing existing files. Try replacing the `iglob` with something like:

```
files = [ 
    os.path.join(args.src_path, 'EXISTENT_FILE'),
    os.path.join(args.src_path, 'NON_EXISTENT_FILE'),
]
```

However: exceptions are costly. It should be cheaper to check for the file using `os.path.exists` (and it's definitely cleaner as you're not relying on a side-effect):

```
import os.path

for file in files:
    if os.path.exists(file):
        sys.stdout.write('File exists: ' + file + '\n')
    else:
        sys.stderr.write('File does not exist: ' + file + '\n')
```

But again, if you obtain `files` by doing a directory lookup, then unless any are deleted between the listing & the testing, they'll always all exist.

Comment: `os.path.exists()` (or better yet, `isfile()`) leaves you open to a race condition, though.

Comment: "Exceptions are costly" might be true for other languages. In Python it is the standard way to do things. Read about [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp).
In addition just using `os-path.exits` might lead to race conditions.

Comment: Executing an exception _is_ costly in Python, regardless of the value of EAFP. You're both right about race conditions with exists(), though.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor The script is generally fed all of the thousands of files in a given directory, and so needs to be able to expand wildcards in the files argument (hence iglob). In this case it clearly won't be looking for nonexistent files. In other cases, however, the script may be directed at only a few specific files in a directory containing other files, and in this case the user could direct it to nonexistent files. Any idea how to handle both cases? BTW: thanks for the clear explanation!

Comment: @pyrogerg: the code in your post should actually handle both cases, the only limitation in your testing was the lack of any non-existent files

Comment: @MatthewTrevor: Thanks, I'll post a new question this evening about how to build the files list from both wildcard expansion or specific files passed to the argument.

Answer (score 2):

Files that don't exist won't be returned by `glob.iglob`. Your `for` loop will only iterate over files that exist.